# configuring mail on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, email, webmail

I installed "mail server" on ubuntu using tasksel --section server
I don't know how to configure it, and I'm failing at proper google searches.

Please help:

1. I need to set up appropriate responces to MX queries so I'm not considered spam
2. set up a couple email addresses so they can be checked (imap or better yet webmail)
3. set up forwarding for particular and "other" usernames (web interface would be best)

Thank you!

P.s.
While adding webmail to tag list I saw "webmin" is this something applicable here?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an e mail server isn't a 'simple' process - [This config guide prolly should walk you through the entire process](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/index.html)

1) is set up at your registar/name server

2) set up imap - you need it for most webmail options - take a look at [roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) or install squirrelmail from your repos

3) you need to set up aliases, or catchall accounts. no idea if there's a webui for it tho

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've already installed it using `tasksel` method. I'm trying to find out what that actually installed and how to configure *that* installation. Any idea?

Comment: 'fraid not. the advice on roundcube and MX still stands tho